AuditD understanding exit,always,exclude,never
I see these 4 exit, always, exclude, and never commonly used in many different combinations like below:
-a exit,always 
-a exit,never
-a exclude,always 
-a exclude,never

I'm trying to understand what each one means and how the positioning of them work.
I've read the manual but still am at odds on the technical side.
Does it matter the placement of the words at all?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/audit.rules.7.html seems to have info on this syntax
